# Optional grouping in a simple python regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

All I want to do is search a string for instances of two consecutive digits. If such an instance is found I want to group it, otherwise return none for that particular groups. I thought this would be trivial, but I can't understand where I'm going wrong. In the example below, removing the optional (?) character gets me the numbers, but in strings without numbers, the `r` evaluates to None, so r.groups() throws an exception.

```
p = re.compile(r'(\d{2})?')
r = p.search('wqddsel78ffgr')
print r.groups()
>>>(None, )    # why not ('78', )?
```

`# --- update/clarification --- #`

Thanks for the answers, but the explanations given are leaving me none-the-wiser. Here's a another go at pin-pointing exactly what it is I don't understand.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'z.*(A)?')
_string = "aazaa90aabcdefA"
result = pattern.search(_string)
result.group()
>>> zaa90aabcdefA
result.groups()
>>> (None, )
```

I understand why `result.group()` produces the result it does, but why doesn't `result.groups()` produce `('A', )`? I thought it worked like this: once the regex hits the `z` it then matches right to the end of the line using `.*`. In spite of `.*` matching everything, the regex engine is aware that it passed over an optional group, and since `?` means it will try to match if it can, it should work backwards to try and match. Replacing `?` with `+` does return `('A', )`. This suggests that `?` won't try and match if it doesn't have to, but this seems to contrast with much of what I've read on the subject (esp. J. Friedl's excellent book).

Comment: For me `print r.groups()` gives `(None,)`

Comment: If you want return just match and not an array, you should use `r.groups()[0]`

Comment: @Eric - quite right, edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
p = re.compile('\D*(\d{2})?')
r = p.search('wqddsel78ffgr')
print r.groups()  # ('78',)

r = p.search('wqddselffgr')
print r.groups()  # (None,)
```

Comment: @Ωmega: `\D` is a shorthand for `[^\d]`

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern

```
(\d{2}|(?!.*\d{2}))
```

(see [this demo](http://ideone.com/MtjAQ6))

If you want be sure there are exactly 2 consecutive digits and not 3 or more, go with

```
((?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)|(?!.*(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)))
```

(see [this demo](http://ideone.com/14patM))

Comment: This matches the empty string, so it just returns `('',)`.

Comment: @dbaupp - It works for me... I have updated my answer with demo links

Comment: Works for me too now! The version with just `(\d{2}|)` was the broken one.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` makes your regex match the empty string. If you omit it, you could just check the result like this:

```
p = re.compile(r'(\d{2})')
r = p.search('wqddsel78ffgr')
print r.groups() if r else ('',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can search for all matches of a RE in a string easily using [`findall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.findall):

```
re.findall(r'\d{2}', 'wqddsel78ffgr') # => ['78']
```

If you don't need the positions where the match occurs, this seems like a simpler way to accomplish what you're doing.

Answer (score -1):

? - is 0 or 1 repetitions. So the regex processor first tries to find 0 repetitions, and... finds it :)

Comment: Wrong, if subtly. Regex processors are greedy, so they'd first try to find the 1 repetition, and only if that fails, accept the lack of a match. Otherwise, patterns that accept a cardinality of `0` would never match anything.

Comment: If that's the case, then why isn't my expression finding the single repetition of two consecutive numbers?

Comment: Because the number of repetitions is pointed - 0 or 1, python search from the begining of the string, and finds FIRST match in the begining of the string = 0 repetitoions of pattern, so for example: findall for this regexp gives: '','','','','','','','78','','','','',''
is it greed or non-greed? Well yes and no, because 0 repetitions is pointed. So give me back my reputation, you are wrong, millimoose